# no matching function for call to CopyConstructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, copy-constructor

there. I have code similar to the one below.

```
struct SomeClass
{
 SomeClass();
};

SomeClass::SomeClass()
{}




template <class K, class T>
struct BaseStruct
{ 
       typedef K kType;
       typedef T tType; 

       kType _key;
       tType _element;

       BaseStruct();       
       BaseStruct(kType& key, tType& element);
       BaseStruct(BaseStruct&);
};


       template <class K,class T>
       BaseStruct<K,T>::BaseStruct()
       {}

       template <class K,class T>
       BaseStruct<K,T>::BaseStruct(kType& key, tType& element)
       { 
         _key=key;
         _element=element;
       }

       template <class K,class T>
       BaseStruct<K,T>::BaseStruct(BaseStruct& BaseStructInstance)
       { 
         _key=BaseStructInstance._key;
         _element=BaseStructInstance._element;
       }

struct DerivedStruct:public BaseStruct<int, SomeClass>
{
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DerivedStruct derivedStructInstance;

    derivedStructInstance=DerivedStruct(0,SomeClass());
}
```

Upon compiling I get the following errors:

```
In function `int main(int, char**)': 
54 no matching function for call to `DerivedStruct::DerivedStruct(int, SomeClass)' 
52 candidates are: DerivedStruct::DerivedStruct() 
52                 DerivedStruct::DerivedStruct(DerivedStruct&) 
Makefile.win [Build Error]  [main.o] Error 1
```

Basically I is saying that the sctuct is missing a copy contructor, whereas I am inizializing the struct by passing its member values.
Moreover I do have a copy constructor.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: What do you expect when you call `DerivedStruct(0,SomeClass())`?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Basically I am inizializing an instance of DerivedStruct

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Which constructor do you expect that snippet to invoke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the C++ Template FAQ:

> The standard says that unqualified names in a template are generally non-dependent and must be looked up when the template is defined. Since the definition of a dependent base class is not known at that time (there may be specialisations of the base class template that have not yet been seen), unqualified names are never resolved to members of the dependent base class. Where names in the template are supposed to refer to base class members or to indirect base classes, they can either be made dependent by qualifying them or brought into the template's scope with a using-declaration.

Solution:

```
struct DerivedStruct : public BaseStruct<int, SomeClass>
{
    using BaseStruct::BaseStruct;
};
```

But that will lead to another problem, because you called this constructor:

```
BaseStruct(kType& key, tType& element);
```

with these arguments:

```
DerivedStruct(0, SomeClass());
```

But a non-const reference cannot bind to temporary values, so this results in a no matching function call error.

Try passing your arguments by constant reference, so that it can accept rvalues, not just lvalues:

```
BaseStruct(kType const& key, tType const& element);
```

[Here is a live demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3373dcb2cc64cfc457e18ea4695373c8-41475e255c735859f2b181fd0d057a6f)

Comment: Constructors don't have names, and that `using` declaration is using the C++11 "inheriting constructors" feature, which is like declaring and defining a number of constructors just for `DerivedStruct`, not just a new way to call the same function.

Comment: Note that the problem doesn't have to do with name lookup. Constructors are not inherited by default. In C++03 you had to explicitly define a `DerivedStruct` ctor or use the C++11 solution in your answer.

Comment: @JesseGood So what is the actually explanation since my solution works?

Comment: Thanks. I have tryed your suggestion. I get 
`template<class K, class T> struct BaseStruct' used without template parameters.  I tryed adding template parameters and I got a cryptic using BaseStruct<int, SomeClass>::BaseStruct' names constructor. How can I fix this?

Comment: @geraldCelente Oh, your compiler is not using the new Standard (C++11). Try adding the `-std=c++11` flag

Comment: @0x499602D2: What your solution does is define a ctor in `DerivedStruct` with the following signature: `DerivedStruct(const int& key, const SomeClass& element) : BaseStruct(key, element)`. (Thats not all inheriting ctors does, but in the example code that is all it does). Whereas in C++03 you had to write this out explicitly, in C++11 you can define all the non-default ctors with one line.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I im using c++03, therefore I think that is the reason I was getting those errors with your suggestion. Anyway, from what I undestand, with C++11 your solution is the way to go.